# Align text within twitter bootstrap nav-list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I want to have text aligned left and right inside the same `<li>` element in `nav-list` of Twitter Bootstrap. Here's my code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  ...
  <li class="active"><a href="/">All<p class="pull-right">100</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="/mon/warnings/">Warning<p class="pull-right">100</p></a></li>
  <li><a href="/mon/errors/">Error<p class="pull-right">100</p></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

And here is how it looks:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Thanks all for replies. Solved this problem in such way:

- replace `<p>` with `<span>`
- add `class="clearfix"` to `<li>` alements

Comment: Inside the same `<li>` or inside the same `<ul`> but different on each `<li>`?

Comment: Inside the same `<li>`: Link is like a string, words are on left, numbers on right side.

Comment: Bootstrap class `text-right` will add `text-align:right` or `pull-right` for `float:right`. Add left instead of right for opposite effect.

Comment: I've tried this, no luck. Look at the picture: text aligned properly, but somehow like stairs, I need one number under another.

Comment: Solved this issue by putting `class="clearfix"` to the `<li>` element. But now I have margins between elements of a list (default height is 26px, clearfix makes it 33px)

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION ONE: CHANGE THE MARKUP:**

Just change your markup a bit. Put the `<p>` outside of the anchor tag.

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  <li class="active"><a href="/">All</a><p class="pull-right">100</p></li>
  <li><a href="/mon/warnings/">Warning</a><p class="pull-right">100</p></li>
  <li><a href="/mon/errors/">Error</a><p class="pull-right">100</p></li>
</ul>


.pull-right {float:right;}
```

**OPTION TWO: CHANGE THE CSS:**

Otherwise if the `<p>` is needed inside of the anchor tag then you could do something like this.

```
a { 
display:block;       
width:100%;
}

p{ float:right;}
```

**EXAMPLE:** *(note I am using a css reset in my example)*

http://jsfiddle.net/vRSMZ/1/

Comment: It might. If so then the issue is that the anchor tag needs to be display block width 100%; And the list needs to be reset so it doesn't have unnecessary padding and margin added by the browser. You can see it working in my fiddle.

Comment: I don't know why we would use a `<p>` in this instance anyway.

Comment: Yeah the `<p>` isn't necessary. Your point on the `<span>` is correct. I just used it because that was what he had.

Comment: I've used `<p>` because official docs said so: _Wrap strings of text in an element with .navbar-text, usually on a <p> tag for proper leading and color._

Comment: Its not technically wrong. In my opinion it is a bit subjective. From a semantics standpoint I fill a `<span>` makes more sense in this context as a `<p>` is typically used for paragraph type content. But regardless, your issue isn't related to the HTML element but to the CSS.

Comment: Anyway, with `<span>` the picture stays the same.

Comment: If I put `<p>` outside of anchor tag, numbers appear on the next line

Comment: That sounds like a css issue. Its possible the anchor tag is taking up max space pushing it to the next line. If you use that method make sure the anchor tag isn't set to display:block; / width:100%;

Comment: You should post your CSS in your question.

Comment: I'm using clean twitter bootstrap v2.2.2, without any changes.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML:**

```
   <ul class="nav nav-list">
      ...
    <li class="active"><a href="/"><label>All</label><span>100</span></a><div class="clr"></div></li>
    <li><a href="/mon/warnings/"><label>Warning</label><span>100</span></a><div class="clr"></div></li>
    <li><a href="/mon/errors/"><label>Error</label><span>100</span></a><div class="clr"></div></li>
      ...
    </ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-list ul li a{ padding:5px 10px; display:block;}
.nav-list ul li a label{ cursor:pointer; display:block; float:left; width:80%;}
.nav-list ul li a span{ cursor:pointer; display:block; float:left; width:20%; text-align-right;}

.clr{ clear:both;}
```

**Note:** Adjust the width of text in the left on label and numbers on the right on span accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
  ...
<li class="active"><a href="/">All<span class="num">100</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/mon/warnings/">Warning<span class="num">100</span></a></li>
<li><a href="/mon/errors/">Error<span class="num">100</span></a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.num{
float: right;
}
```

I changed your `<p>` to `<span>` because that makes more sense... Then added a `.nums` class to the span, and floated that right.